# Query status of active/hospitalized corda-flows

Tags: corda

I have a flow `MyFlow` that is invoked over RPC with some specific `args`, creates a tx putting some of the `args` in the output-state and then invokes `subFlow(FinalityFlow(...))`. Pretty standard I think. The RPC-client may invoke a bunch of those flows concurrently.
Now if the notary or a receiving node is down, `MyFlow` may get suspended and retried.

What I'd like to do now is to query/report to a user/node-operator the information about which transactions are currently "pending", i.e. being retried. Ideally I'd like to pull out the tx-id and the `args` of the unfinished instances of `MyFlow`. I can't seem to use `ProgressTracker`, since its `Steps` need to be defined up-front (i.e. in the Flow-constructor, where I don't know the tx-id yet), and the `label`-String anyway doesn't seem like a good carrier of structured data. `AuditService` looks like a good candidate since it has access to the steps `extraAuditData`, but it appears to only have the do-nothing `DummyAuditService` implementation, and I cannot hook a custom implementation without changing `AbstractNode.kt` (or can I ?).
Any ideas how this could be achieved ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the active flows from the node shell using `flow watch`.

Retrieving information about the flows running on a node requires internal information to be retrieved. This is not something that a developer can do without hacking corda around.

It might be possible to get something working using `stateMachineRecordedTransactionMappingFeed` or `stateMachinesFeed` but what you can achieve is going to be limited.

Further tooling around running flows and hospitalised flows is something that might be added to Corda in the future.